# Understanding formula compressed gamma

Tags: math, rgb, grayscale

I found a formulas on wikipedia where the formulas for converting from `RGB` to `Grayscale` are shown. If the receipt of a linear shade of gray is understandable. The formulas for a compressed shade of gray are not clear.

[image]

What is mean: `1.055`, `1/2.4 (I think 2.4 - gray gamma, but why 2.4 not 2.2?)`, `0.055`...and other coefs. I did not find any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason given in “[A Standard Default Color Space for the Internet](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB)” is:

> The effect of the above equations is to closely fit a straightforward gamma 2.2 curve with an slight offset to allow for invertability in integer math.

My interpretation is that the formula is easier to calculate when using integer-variables (e.g. not floating point) and this was important at the time.

Comment: I do not quite understand what means: `invertability in integer math`. Can you give an example?